# How to stay at the same position in the RecyclerView even after fetching the updated data from the Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items in a `RecyclerView` that fetched from the `Firestore` database. Whenever I add, delete or edit an item I call respective function to make changes in the `Firestore` and then I call the `getProductListFromFireStore()` to update the `RecyclerView`. But the problem that I have is every time I make these changes, I go to the top of the list. I want to stay where I was even after adding/deleting or editing. How can I do that?

I didn't have the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my code earlier, this was added to check if this will do the job, I do not know if I have done this right.

The following function is called when the product list is successfully fetched from the `Firestore`

```
    fun successProductsListFromFireStore(productsList: ArrayList<Product>) {
    hideProgressDialog()

    if (productsList.size > 0) {

        binding.rvMyProductItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding.rvMyProductItems.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val adapterProducts =
            MyProductsListAdapter(requireActivity(), productsList, this@ProductsFragment)
        binding.rvMyProductItems.adapter = adapterProducts

        adapterProducts.notifyDataSetChanged()

    } else {
        binding.rvMyProductItems.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.tvNoProductsFound.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to use DiffUtill. It automatically update only changed items and if at least one item on screen was not changed then u will stay on the same position